# Mostrar y ocultar formularios con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página en la que dispongo de dos formularios, cada uno de ellos con sus campos.
Uno guarda datos sobre obras y el otro sobre reformas.
Estaba programando un botón o un radio, conforme haga click en uno de ellos y me vacíe los campos del formulario que no pedí y me muestre el que sí clickeé en el radio o en el botón. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso con JavaScript?

Aquí enseño mi código:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-center">¿Qué quieres presupuestar?</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">                                
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="obra">Obra</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id=reforma>Reforma</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-6 collapse reforma">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <img th:src="@{/images/bano.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <label>Largo:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="largo" /><br>
                        <label>Ancho:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="ancho" /><br>
                        <label>Alto:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="alto" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Nº de sanitarios: </label>
               <input class="form-control" type="number" id="qt_sn" name="cantidad" min="0"><br>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
               <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="precio" />
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Modificacion instalaciones (si/no):</label><br>
               <input type="radio" id="yes" name="opcion" value="30">
               <label for="yes">S&iacute;</label><br>
               <input type="radio" id="no" name="opcion" value="30">
               <label for="no">No</label><br>
           </div>


           <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" href="#">Calcular presupuesto</a>
       </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 collapse reforma"> 
     <form>
        <fieldset>
            <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>Superficie total a construir (m2) * 1100€/m2 * Calidad material (baja/media/alta)</p>
        
            <div>
                <img th:src="@{/images/obra.png}" style="width: 250px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Superficie total a construir (m2):</label><br>
                <input  class="form-control" type="number" name="superficie" id="superficie" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="calidad">Calidad material:</label><br>
                <input  type="radio" id="baja" name="calidad" value="0.8">
                <label for="baja">Baja</label><br>
                <input  type="radio" id="media" name="calidad" value="1">
                <label for="media">Media</label><br>
                <input  type="radio" id="alta" name="calidad" value="1.3">
                <label for="alta">Alta</label><br>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="boton1" href="#">Calcular presupuesto</a>
                                    
            <div class="text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
            </div>
      </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Esos son los formularios indicados. A continuación muestro el código js:

```
    $(function() {
        var pintadoObra = false;
        var pintadoReforma = false;
        $("#obra").click(function() {
        if (!pintadoObra){
            $(".obra").removeClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = true;
        } else {
            $(".obra").addClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = false;
        }
    })

    $("#reforma").click(function() {
        if (!pintadoObra){
            $(".reforma").removeClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = true;
        } else {
            $(".reforma").addClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = false;
        }
    })
```

});

Mi objetivo es que cuando uno de los 2 formularios se muestre, el otro se oculte y se vacien los campos. Además me mostrará un alert el cuál indicará los cambios. ¿Qué estrategia podría seguir para hacer esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto a ver si te funciona.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#obra").click(function() {
            $("#formReforma").hide();
            $("#formObra").show();
            $("#formReforma").trigger("reset");
        });

        $("#reforma").click(function() {
            $("#formObra").hide();
            $("#formReforma").show();
            $("#formObra").trigger("reset");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aquí hacemos desaparecer o aparecer el formulario según el botton al que clickes y lo reseteas con trigger("reset"), que dispara el evento reset y te limpia el formulario

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente ejemplo se despliega/oculta el div que contiene el form según el boton que se presione y se elimina el contenido ingresado en el div que se oculta

1. Agregar IDs a los elementos a ocupar para facilitar su acceso

> ```
> <div id="divReforma" class="col-md-6 collapse reforma">
>     <form id="formReforma" action="" method="post">
> ```

y

> ```
> <div  id="divObra"  class="col-md-6 collapse reforma"> 
>      <form id="formObra">
> ```

Luego en el script agregamos

Iniciamos elementos ocultos

> document.getElementById("divObra").style.display = "none";
> document.getElementById("divReforma").style.display = "none";

Cambiamos el estado mostrar/ocultar con su reset de los campos del form correspondientes

```
    function functionShowObra() {   
var x = document.getElementById("divObra");   
var xForm = document.getElementById("formObra");    
if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";   } 
else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                xForm.reset();    } }  

function functionShowReforma() {   
var x = document.getElementById("divReforma");   
var xForm = document.getElementById("formReforma");    
if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";   } 
else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                xForm.reset();    
        } }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
            $(function() {
        var pintadoObra = false;
        var pintadoReforma = false;
        $("#obra").click(function() {
        if (!pintadoObra){
            $(".obra").removeClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = true;
        } else {
            $(".obra").addClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = false;
        }
    })

    $("#reforma").click(function() {
        if (!pintadoObra){
            $(".reforma").removeClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = true;
        } else {
            $(".reforma").addClass("collapse");
            pintadoObra = false;
        }
    })

});

});

//iniciar ocultos
document.getElementById("divObra").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("divReforma").style.display = "none";


//cambiar estado mostrar/ocultar
function functionShowObra() {
  var x = document.getElementById("divObra");
  var xForm = document.getElementById("formObra"); 
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    xForm.reset(); 
  }
} 
//cambiar estado mostrar/ocultar
function functionShowReforma() {
  var x = document.getElementById("divReforma");
  var xForm = document.getElementById("formReforma"); 
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    xForm.reset(); 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title text-center">¿Qué quieres presupuestar?</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">                                
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button onclick="functionShowObra()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="obra">Obra</button>
                    <button onclick="functionShowReforma()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id=reforma>Reforma</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="divReforma" class="col-md-6 collapse reforma">
        <form id="formReforma" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <img th:src="@{/images/bano.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <label>Largo:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="largo" /><br>
                            <label>Ancho:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="ancho" /><br>
                            <label>Alto:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="alto" />
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
    
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Nº de sanitarios: </label>
                   <input class="form-control" type="number" id="qt_sn" name="cantidad" min="0"><br>
               </div>
    
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
                   <input class="form-control" type="number" step="any" name="precio" />
               </div>
    
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Modificacion instalaciones (si/no):</label><br>
                   <input type="radio" id="yes" name="opcion" value="30">
                   <label for="yes">S&iacute;</label><br>
                   <input type="radio" id="no" name="opcion" value="30">
                   <label for="no">No</label><br>
               </div>
    
    
               <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" href="#">Calcular presupuesto</a>
           </fieldset>
       </form>
    </div>



    <div  id="divObra"  class="col-md-6 collapse reforma"> 
         <form id="formObra">
            <fieldset>
                <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>Superficie total a construir (m2) * 1100€/m2 * Calidad material (baja/media/alta)</p>
            
                <div>
                    <img th:src="@{/images/obra.png}" style="width: 250px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Superficie total a construir (m2):</label><br>
                    <input  class="form-control" type="number" name="superficie" id="superficie" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="calidad">Calidad material:</label><br>
                    <input  type="radio" id="baja" name="calidad" value="0.8">
                    <label for="baja">Baja</label><br>
                    <input  type="radio" id="media" name="calidad" value="1">
                    <label for="media">Media</label><br>
                    <input  type="radio" id="alta" name="calidad" value="1.3">
                    <label for="alta">Alta</label><br>
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="boton1" href="#">Calcular presupuesto</a>
                                        
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
                </div>
          </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>
    
    

</body>
</html>
```